# Material UI - issue with flex wrap in my template

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui

How to achieve responsive template using flex wrapping technique?

```
<Box
            sx={{
              padding: 0,
              margin: 0,
              listStyle: "none",
              display: "flex",
              flexFlow: "wrap row",
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
            }}
          >
            <Box backgroundColor="red">one</Box>
            <Box backgroundColor="blue">two</Box>
            <Box backgroundColor="orange">three</Box>
          </Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my public/index.html,

I had removed the below line earlier

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Now I add the line. The template is now responsive.